# Fix minimum scale factor of text

Tags: ios, swift, autoresize

I have a highscore label that is constrained to the superview with aspect ratio and uses autoshrink (minimum font scale) to resize text for different devices. However, the text keeps resizing depending how large the highscore is. After autoshrinking, I want the font size to be fixed to the minimum scale factor - how would I do this?

Comment: I would imagine that you need to do this with code from the beginning, instead of using storyboard constraints. Then you can set the size in `viewDidLoad` just once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know what the code would consist of?

Comment: Well the sizing could be done by font: `label.font = UIFont(name: "favoriteFont", size: idealSize)`. I don't know how you're going to detect the device size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly bizzare. I couldn't find a way of fixing the minimum scale but I discovered that, while having an aspect ratio constraint in place, you can reduce the number of lines by one and change the width of the label/button without the text adjusting to it.